# Validating Error on deployment in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, kubectl

I have tried to deploy the `producer-service` app with MySQL database in the Kubernetes cluster. When i try to deploy `producer app` then the following validation error has thrown.

```
error: error validating "producer-deployment.yml": error validating data: apiVersion not set; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

**producer-deployment.yml**

```
apiVerion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: producer-app
  labels:
    name: producer-app
spec:
  ports:
    -nodePort: 30163
    port: 9090
    targetPort: 9090
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: producer-app
  type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: producer-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: producer-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: producer-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: producer
          image: producer:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
               configMapKeyRef:
                name: db-config
                key: host
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
               configMapKeyRef:
                name: db-config
                key: name
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
               secretKeyRef:
                name: db-user
                key: username
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
               secretKeyRef:
                name: db-user
                key: password
```

i have tried to find the error or typo within the config file but still, couldn't. What is wrong with the `producer-deployment.yml` file

Answer (score 2):

- Please change the first line in producer-deployment.yml. Letter s is missing.

From

apiVerion: v1

To

apiVersion: v1

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues:

1. It would be `apiVersion: v1` not `apiVerion: v1` in the `Service`
2. wrong `Spec.ports` formation of `Service`. As `nodePort`, `port`, `targetPort` and  `protocol` are under the `ports` as a list but your did wrong formation.

your service yaml should be like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: producer-app
  labels:
    name: producer-app
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30163
      port: 9090
      targetPort: 9090
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: producer-app
  type: NodePort
```

So your overall `yaml` should be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: producer-app
  labels:
    name: producer-app
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30163
      port: 9090
      targetPort: 9090
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: producer-app
  type: NodePort

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: producer-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: producer-app
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: producer-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: producer
          image: producer:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-config
                  key: host
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-config
                  key: name
            - name: DB_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-user
                  key: username
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-user
                  key: password
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the first line: "apiVerion" should be "apiVersion".

Answer (score 0):

Your first error(there are more than 1) just point you to the place where you should start your investigation from..

```
error validating data: apiVersion not set;
```

As you know, each object in kubernetes has its own apiVersion.
Check [Understanding Kubernetes Objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/), especially [Required Fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#required-fields) part:

> In the .yaml file for the Kubernetes object you want to create, you'll
> need to set values for the following fields:
>
> `apiVersion` - Which version of the Kubernetes API you're using to
> create this object
>
> `kind` - What kind of object you want to create
>
> `metadata` - Data that helps uniquely identify the object, including a
> name string, UID, and optional namespace
>
> `spec` - What state you desire
> for the object The precise format of the object spec is different for
> every Kubernetes object, and contains nested fields specific to that
> object.
>
> The Kubernetes API Reference can help you find the `spec` format
> for all of the objects you can create using Kubernetes.

You can check [Latest 1.20 API here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20)

These values are mandatory and you wont be able to create object without them. So please, next time read more carefully errors you receive.